# Minimal Images & XAML-Defined shapes?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is it good practise to build my UI with minimal images and define things like shapes/paths etc in the XAML?

If so, what are the advantages of this approach and/or other approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, having been creating UIs in WPF for the past 7 years, yes it is good practice in general.  However, it depends entirely on the aesthetic you want to provide.  Static images add to your application size but can be easily cached making them performant.  They're a little inflexible as an image will distort the second you try to stretch it's dimensions.  Images are fine if you don't need it to be dynamically sized.

However, you'll find that defining your UI entirely with markup can be a lot more complicated and can stray from your pixel-perfect mockups at various sizes.  Gradients produced in WPF are inferior quality, you'll see visible banding if the gradient spans too far.

Performance doesn't play much of a role unless you intend to use a lot of DropShadowEffects (do not use legacy BitmapEffects).  Stick to the lightweight elements (such as `FrameworkElement`) when templating controls.

By the way, there's a fantastic and recently *free* icon studio called [**Syncfusion Metro Studio 1**](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/metrostudio) which is a fairly extensive icon pack that allows you to customize the size, background, foreground, & padding, then it lets you choose if you'd like to save it as an image or export it as a XAML path.  The benefit of using XAML paths are that they will be perfectly scalable and you can dynamically change the fill color, could be set by the user even.  Something that is possible with images using a custom color overlay shader but very resource intensive.

Comment: I've definitely experience the gradient banding issue, how would you counter this? But excellent answer!

Comment: @KianMayne Avoid using large-scale gradients.  The problem is that it's a 32-bit color space and that means there's a maximum of 255 stops.  It becomes apparent you're dealing with 255 stops when you try stretching those stops over a large monitor.  No way around it except maybe stretching a PNG image created in an image editor.  Try this in [Kaxaml](http://kaxaml.com/) to see banding easily.
    `<LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5">
        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Black"/>
        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#ff777777"/>
      </LinearGradientBrush>`

Comment: That's a pain, I can see banding in my application already, I'll try the png approach, how big do you think I should make the image?

Comment: With a product like Photoshop you'll still get banding, though not as bad as WPF for some reason.  There are some simple techniques out there to reduce the perception of banding by using gaussian blur/adding noise, with varying degrees of success. I'd still try to work with the smallest gradient that you can -- maybe try other styles that don't require expansive gradients but several smaller ones, it sounds hacky but it can give you a decent end product.

Comment: Well my gradient is an offset of a radial one, so I guess I could have a block of colour then the image of the start of the radial center and make it fade in